# Words containing given letters

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I'm trying to solve a task with the following content:

Create a function that retrieves the word and string of required letters and returns True if the word has all the required letters at least once.

My code looks like that:

```py
def uses_only(letters, word):
    letters = str(input("Enter letters : "))
    word = str(input("Enter word : "))

    if letters in word:
        print("T")
    else:
        print("F")

uses_only(input, input)
```

But it doesn't work properly, becouse it returns F if the letter occurs more than once in the word. I searched the internet, but I didn't find anything that would help me. Can somebody explain me how to solve this task correctly?

Comment: You are already parsing the variables to check in the function call, there should be no need to get the input of the user again. Either change ```def uses_only(letters, word):``` to ```def uses_only():``` or remove the input part at the beginning of the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood what you're trying to do.

This is a possible solution: the function checks whether each letter exists at least once in the word.

```
def f(word, letters):
    return all(l in word for l in letters)
```

For example:

```
f("information", "oat") # true
f("information", "zfa") # false
```

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it on this way, probably its something what you was trying:

```
def uses_only(letters, word):
    letters = str(input("Enter letters : "))
    word = str(input("Enter word : "))

    for letter in letters:
        if letter not in word:
            return False
    return True

print (uses_only(input, input))
```

Comment: I was trying to do that in this way. Thanks a lot